# Do the makers of Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle consider the film to be science fiction or fantasy?

Tags: science-fiction-genre, fantasy-genre, jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle

I've been in an argument with one of my teachers. I'd like to know if there has been any definitive statement from the makers of *Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle* as to whether they consider the film to be science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: Since opinion is everywhere, I submit mine - call it modern fantasy.  Magic in the real world is a common theme these days.  I don't really understand where sci-fi comes into it, unless one of you is fixated on the game console, or the timeline changing, which OK, sure, there's a sci-fi element there, but it's mostly a proxy for magic to use.

Comment: @Radhil I would tend to agree, particularly since wikipedia lists it as a fantasy movie and it was nominated for a Saturn Award in the fantasy category rather than the science fiction category. Plus it's based on the original Jumanji, which was very clearly fantasy.

Comment: I'm curious as to which of you is backing the science fiction argument? I'd like to think it's you & not your teacher, if only because the idea that someone employed to educate could have such a wrong-headed opinion is a little depressing, it's not a promising indicator for the education of his/her students :)

Comment: Unfortunately, My teacher is the one who considers it a science fiction movie. But, I showed him your comment as well as all the others, and I have a feeling that he is going to change his mind. Thank you!!  @Pelinore

Answer (score 10):

The film, although containing some slight elements of science fiction (the characters, for example enter a fantasy world via a framing story involving a magical games console) was **marketed exclusively as a fantasy / adventure story.**

The initial [casting call sheet](https://productionlist.com/atlanta-featured-roles-casting-call-for-jumanji/) is a good example of this;

> Jumanji is **an upcoming American fantasy adventure film** directed by
> Jake Kasdan and written by Scott Rosenberg. It is a reimagining of the
> 1995 film of the same name, and will have a tribute to the late Robin
> Williams.

The [blurb released to pre-reviewers](https://www.openwriting.com/2017/12/jumanji-welcome-jungle-film-review-2017/)

> Summary: JUMANJI: WELCOME TO THE JUNGLE is **a US fantasy action
> adventure comedy** in which four high school students are drawn into the
> jungle setting of a video game.

The [press-release issued at various comic-cons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wV5NXr1bMIk) where the film's trailer was previewed

> JUMANJI: WELCOME TO THE JUNGLE (also known as JUMANJI 2) is **an
> upcoming American fantasy adventure film, directed by Jake Kasdan and
> written by Scott Rosenberg.** Starring Dwayne Johnson, Kevin Hart, Jack
> Black, KAREN GILLEN, and Nick Jonas, the tables are turned as four
> teenagers are sucked into the Jumanji board game world - pitted
> against rhinos, black mambas, and an endless variety of jungle traps
> and puzzles. To beat the game and return to the real world with their
> lives, they'll have to start seeing things in an entirely different
> way... The film is scheduled for a Christmas release, hitting screens
> in the US on 22nd December, 2017.

The [categories self-selected by the filmmakers](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/releases/jumanji-welcome-jungle-2017) when issuing the film for BBFC categorisation

> **GENRE(S)** **Fantasy,** Comedy, Adventure
>
> ...
>
> **SUMMARY** JUMANJI: WELCOME TO THE JUNGLE is **a US fantasy action adventure comedy** in which four high school students are drawn into the jungle setting of a video game.